# Installation problem xdg-desktop-menu: No writable system menu directory found

Tags: software-installation, xdg, debian-installer

When installing the IBM tsm backup client I have the following message on lucid (works on precise)

```
> sudo apt-get upgrade
Setting up tsm-client (6.4.0.7-3) ...
xdg-desktop-menu: No writable system menu directory found.
dpkg: error processing tsm-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tsm-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer [on linux bug reports](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/33316). It is a bug in xdg. I have found that you can get around it by simply creating the folder it is looking for. i.e.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/desktop-directories/
```

Comment: What!? I don't understand. Creating this directory fixed my problem ([installing spotify-client](https://www.spotify.com/no/download/linux/)), but nothing was put into that directory. It's still completely empty.

Comment: I guess xdg just wants to look in the directory and then does things differently depending on whether there's anything in there. It gets upset if it can't look in the directory (a bug in xdg).

Comment: Good stuff. It's been over a year, and today I'm setting up my new work laptop. Trying to install Spotify I got this error again and had to Google it, found this answer and my own old comment. Trippy. Also it's pretty disappointing that such an old bug is still present and bothering me in Debian 9.1